# Random Color Change Each Iteration

Tags: java, graphics

While using an ArrayList, I can't seem to figure out how to reset and re-apply the random color for each iteration of the for loop. I am trying to reset and apply my random color every time my XLeft position is changed. This is only a section of one class I am using, and my getMax() was defined by a Scanner input.  Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class BarChart {

private int width, height;
private ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
private Random generator = new Random();
int red = generator.nextInt(255);
int green = generator.nextInt(255);
int blue = generator.nextInt(255);
private Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);


public BarChart(int aWidth, int aHeight) {

    width = aWidth;
    height = aHeight;

}

public void add(double inputValues) {
    values.add(inputValues);
}

public double getMax() {

    double max = values.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if ((values.get(i)) > max)
            max = values.get(i);

    }
    return max;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

    int xLeft = 0;
    double barWidth = width / values.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

        double barHeight = (values.get(i) / getMax()) * height;
        Rectangle bar = new Rectangle(xLeft, height - ((int) barHeight),
                (int) barWidth, (int) barHeight);
        g2.setColor(randomColor);
        g2.fill(bar);
        xLeft = (int) (xLeft + barWidth);
        xLeft++;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is randomColor defined?

Comment: It is defined at the top of my class.   int red = generator.nextInt(255);
 int green = generator.nextInt(255);
 int blue = generator.nextInt(255);
 private Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

Comment: If you want the random color to change at each iteration, then make it change at each iteration, by assigning a new value to it *inside* the loop.

Comment: I am kind of new at this so that is what is confusing me. I don't quite understand how to change the color after each new xLeft. I have tried using if statements and another for statement, but every time, my random color is the same as the previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're defining your random color once, before the loop. This means that when you run the loop, it uses the same "random color" each time through. You need to move the definition of the random color into the loop, so that it runs with each iteration.

EDIT (based on your comments):

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

int xLeft = 0;
double barWidth = width / values.size();

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

    double barHeight = (values.get(i) / getMax()) * height;
    Rectangle bar = new Rectangle(xLeft, height - ((int) barHeight),
            (int) barWidth, (int) barHeight);

    red = generator.nextInt(255); 
    green = generator.nextInt(255);
    blue = generator.nextInt(255);
    randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

    g2.setColor(randomColor);
    g2.fill(bar);
    xLeft = (int) (xLeft + barWidth);
    xLeft++;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried doing that and it still executes the same. Both my random number and color generator were set as instance variables so they were still accessible, right?

Comment: I'll just post all of that class. Editing the initial post now.

Comment: As I said, you are only defining the random color once, at the top of your class. You need to create a new random color each time the for loop in the `draw` method runs. You can define the `int` and color variables as instance variables, as you have done, but you need to change them every time the loop executes.

Comment: Wow...I was completely over-thinking this...been staring at this for hours. I had tried a variation of that after your post, but wasn't saving the new color as I should. Thanks for the help.